# Wordpress - changing foundation menu icon for custom one

Tags: html, css, wordpress, zurb-foundation

I am using `zurb foundation 6` and in it's `title bar` I would like to change the `menu-icon`, for the image that I have. I am not sure how to do this, and how to get assets from the custom theme in `wordpress`.

Since, this wasn't working:

```
.menu-icon {
  background: url('/assets/images/menu-icon.svg');
}
```

I have tried with this, but that is not working as well:

```
.menu-icon {
  background: get_template_directory_uri('/assets/images/menu-icon.svg');
}
```

Not sure, how can I pull the assets in the css for custom themes in wordpress and changing the zurb menu icon for my own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.menu-icon` background image is managed in `menu-icon::after`, as mix of background color and box-shadows. So if you want to add your own image, you have to add it to `menu-icon::after` and adjust code to make your image the way you want it.
Example (not a perfect one, but to show you what I mean):

```
.menu-icon::after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    content: '';
    background-image: url(https://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/assets/img/logos/zurb-logo.svg);
    background-size: 150%;
    background-position: 7px 11px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Also just to confirm for OP, get_template_directory_uri() is PHP code and won't work in CSS.

Comment: Yes, OP also has to care about their image path, and to use correct syntax.

Comment: Thanks, but do you know how can I pull the image from the custom theme in WordPress? I can't get that to work

Comment: You'd just need to give the full url http://XXXX/XXXX/assets/images/menu-icon.svg

It is better to give static urls instead of relative ones.

Comment: @Leff Does get_template_directory_uri work at all? You should test it outside of CSS. But as a PHP code it should be outside of CSS. There are ways to add PHP code inside CSS, but I would avoid them if not necessary.
Inside CSS you can use real path to the image, or you can add CSS in PHP, which is also not recommended.